# Backpropagation in convolution

Tags: neural-network, convolution, backpropagation, deep-learning

I am having some trouble understanding how the backpropagation is working in the convolution layers. Indeed, after calculating the error in hidden layers, we can represent it in an error image. But after that, how do I update the kernel?

I give an example in the Figure below : we have an image error (l+1) (with the backpropagation calculated) connected to the parent's output (l) with the associated kernel K.

At the position (x, y),the error will be : err = e1.k'1+e2.k'2+...+e9.k'9 (k' the coefficients of the kernel in (l+1)). So, if we have no moment, no activation function and no learning rate, then the correction of K will be :

K1 = K1 + err * e1

K2 = K2 + err * e2

...

Is this first explanation correct ?
After that, how propage error ? Do we propagate error only at the (x, y) position or at (x+kx, y+ky) position with (kx, ky) the filter K position?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBJyZ.png

Comment: If you don't good answers here, CrossValidated at www.stats.stackexchange.com might be a better place to ask machine learning questions.

Answer (score -2):

Backpropagation works in convolutional networks just like how it works in deep neural nets. The only difference is that due to the weight sharing mechanism in the convolution process, the amount of update applied to the weights in the convolution layer is also shared.